# Mime type of uploaded zip file is application/octet

Tags: php, upload, mime-types

I have a simple file upload that only allows zip files. On my machine (Windows 7, Firefox 19.0.2) it works fine.  On another machine (Windows 8, Firefox 19.0.2) the file type check fails when I upload the same file.

On the Windows 8 machine the mime type of the .zip is `application/octet`.  Why?  Also, I haven't come across this mime type before.  I was expecting `application/octet-stream`.

What is `application/octet` used for and why is it different on the other machine?

Comment: Don't use mime types for file type validation, open the file and see what's in it.

Comment: @Musa It's a trivial test.  You didn't really answer my question.

Comment: That's why its not in the answer section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never heard of `application/octet`.  Guessing it is just equivalent to `application/octet-stream`.  It is just the catch all anyway.

Maybe take a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775147%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

> The MIME types "text/plain" and "application/octet-stream" are termed
>   ambiguous because they generally do not provide clear indications of
>   which application or CLSID should be associated as the content
>   handler...
>
> ...and **defaulting to the final determined MIME type of
>   "application/octet-stream."** Other types of files, such as .reg files,
>   behave similarly.
>
> Finally, if no file name extension is found, or one is found with no
>   associated MIME type or registered application, the MIME type
>   "text/plain" is returned if the data scan indicated predominantly
>   text, or "application/octet-stream" if the data scan indicated binary,
>   because this is the furthest correct determination that could be made.